# Minimizing number of nodes in polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins

I'm building a web application that will be transferring polygons from server to client. Initially, the shapefile is coming from an external source that I have no control over.

Often, I find polygons with way too many points to describe a straight line. The result is, the size of the payload increases and therefore the fetch takes longer. This obviously isn't an issue with only a few polygons, but it will add up as more shapes are added to my dataset and I'd like to optimize bandwidth.

[image: too many points - qgis]

Is there a plugin, or native QGIS function that will take some kind of tolerance/variance as input, and produce (approximately) the same polygon with much fewer actual points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the ultra-classic [douglas–peucker algorithm](http://www.google.com/#q=qgis+douglas%E2%80%93peucker) is probably the best solution for you,

Comment: I should add that PostGIS has [`ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html) which implements the Douglas-Peucker algo. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There is a **Simplify features** tool in **Advanced Digitizing** toolbar that does exactly what you're describing.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=editing#simplify-feature

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the online tool mapshaper http://mapshaper.com/test/MapShaper.swf to "produce (approximately) the same polygon with much fewer actual points" give it a try to see if it fits your needs